# Text Wrap with algorithm2e

Tags: floats, algorithm2e

I'm using `algorithm2e` for algorithms and for some of the longer algorithms, (eyeballed at > 50% of a page) there is no other text on the page with just an embarrassing amount of white space above and below the algorithm. The other figures and floats in my document are positioned just fine with text flowing below them, and I have no special commands regarding the placement of floats. I've checked the `algorithm2e` documentation, but there is nothing about this.

Any tips?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You may have a look on [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436).

Comment: Can't tell without you giving specifics by way of a minimal working example (MWE). However, I have seen places where LaTeX prefers a page break if putting extra text on that page would break "awkwardly". For example, if the float were followed by a new section, and there was room for the section header, but only a line or two of section material, LaTeX may decide to move the whole section to the next page.  Likewise if an equation is in the mix.

Comment: Have a look at http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/39017/15925 .  My guess is that your `\floatpagefraction (default 0.5)` needs adjusting.  Otherwise please provide a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228)

Comment: No MWE: can't really hope to help